# how can i generate n unique random numbers in sybase

Tags: random, numbers, sybase, sap-ase

i need to generate n unique random numbers in sybase ase. The number n will be specified while executing the required stored proc.. 
ex : exec procedurename 12
should return 12 unique random numbers.

Is there a way to do this in sybase ase?

Thanks
rinu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand()` and `rand2()` are the built in random number functions for SAP Sybase ASE.

More information on these and other functions can be found here:

[Reference Manual:Building Blocks](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/CHDIHGDF.htm)

Comment: needed integers ..got it with this : round((RAND() * (10^100)),0)

Comment: Many random fuctions return a value between 0 and 1, and it is then up to the developer to decide how to satisfty their requirements.